# VBA Loop directory removing (by sheet name) all sheets but one from each workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have previously posted on here about using VBA to loop through a folder and remove known passwords from each workbook therein. Thought I could use the same code and just insert code the removes all sheets except one (by reference to sheet name), but no such luck.

Any VBA pros out there that can help?

```
Sub loop_sheets_del()

Dim MyFile as String, str As String, MyDir = "[directory]"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While Myfile <> ""
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
If ws.Name <> "name of sheet to keep" Then
ws.Delete
End If

Next ws (error indicates problem is here)

ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End With
MyFile = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: next is for ```for loops``` you don't have one of those.

Comment: @Warcupine Yes.  I believe that is correct.  However, I cannot figure out how to insert the sheet deleting code into a loop such that all folders in the directory can be processed.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the first part of the requisite `For Each` loop.

Also best to use a `Workbook` variable to refer to each workbook being opened and modified:

```
Do While Myfile <> ""
   Dim MyWB As Workbook   
   Set MyWB = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)

   For Each ws in MyWB.Worksheets
       If ws.Name <> "name of sheet to keep" Then
           ws.Delete
       End If
   Next
   
   myWB.Close True

   MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Yes! that seemed to work.  Tried it on a folder with three test files, now about to run it on a huge folder with hundreds of such workbooks.

Comment: This will of course fail if the workbook doesn't contain one sheet to be kept, since you can't delete all worksheets from a workbook.

Comment: Oh, I am keeping one sheet, the workbook is just so large that processing the data from that one key sheet is choking my Python code.  So, I have tinkered with VBA already (have that one looping script to remove known password from a dir of workbooks).  But, this sheet removal script was dogging me.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Sheets

- In the current setup, the following will delete all sheets except the one named `Master` in all files with the `xls*` extension (e.g. `xls`, `xlsx`, `xlsm`: do not use wild characters in the code; it is covered by `Instr`) in the specified folder `F:\Test\2020\64504925` and all of its subfolders.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Run only this sub after you have adjusted the path, the worksheet name
' and the file extension.
Sub loopSubFolders()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    loopSubFoldersInitialize "F:\Test\2020\64504925", "Master", "xls"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Sheets deleted.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

Sub loopSubFoldersInitialize(ByVal FolderPath As String, _
                             ByVal SheetName As String, _
                             Optional ByVal FileExtension As String = "")
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    loopSubFoldersRecursion fso, fso.GetFolder(FolderPath), SheetName, _
                            FileExtension
End Sub

Sub loopSubFoldersRecursion(fso As Object, _
                            fsoFolder As Object, _
                            ByVal SheetName As String, _
                            Optional ByVal FileExtension As String = "")

    Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
    Dim fsofile As Object
    
    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
        loopSubFoldersRecursion fso, fsoSubFolder, SheetName, FileExtension
    Next
    
    If FileExtension = "" Then
        For Each fsofile In fsoFolder.Files
            'Debug.Print fsofile.Path
        Next
    Else
        For Each fsofile In fsoFolder.Files
            If InStr(1, fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile.Path), _
                     FileExtension, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Dim wb As Workbook
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fsofile.Path)
                deleteSheetsExceptOneByName wb, SheetName
                Debug.Print fsofile.Path
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
            End If
        Next fsofile
    End If

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Deletes all sheets in a workbook except the one specified
'               by its name.
' Remarks:      The code uses the dictionary to hold all the sheet names.
'               Only if the specified sheet exists, it will be removed from
'               the dictionary and the remaining sheets in it will be deleted
'               in one go. Otherwise no action will be taken.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function deleteSheetsExceptOneByName(Book As Workbook, _
                                     ByVal SheetName As String) _
         As Long
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "deleteSheetsExceptOneByName"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.

    ' Validate workbook.
    If Book Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NoWorkbook
    End If
    
    ' Define dictionary.
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        ' Write sheet names to dictionary.
        Dim sh As Object
        For Each sh In Book.Sheets
            .Add sh.Name, Empty
        Next sh
        ' Validate sheet name string.
        If Not .Exists(SheetName) Then
            GoTo NoSheet
        End If
        ' Remove sheet name string from the dictionary.
        .Remove (SheetName)
        ' Validate number of sheets.
        If .Count = 0 Then
            GoTo OneSheet
        End If
        ' Delete sheets.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Book.Sheets(.Keys).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        deleteSheetsExceptOneByName = .Count
        GoTo SheetsDeleted
    End With
    
NoWorkbook:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No workbook ('Nothing')."
    GoTo ProcExit

NoSheet:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No sheet named '" & SheetName _
              & "' in workbook."
    GoTo ProcExit

OneSheet:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Sheet '" & Book.Sheets(SheetName).Name _
              & "' is the only sheet in workbook."
    GoTo ProcExit

SheetsDeleted:
    If deleteSheetsExceptOneByName > 1 Then
        Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Deleted " _
                  & deleteSheetsExceptOneByName & " sheets in workbook."
    Else
        Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Deleted 1 sheet in workbook."
    End If
    GoTo ProcExit

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

ProcExit:

End Function
```

Comment: Friendly hint: `GoTo` statements - especially repeated ones - are commonly associated with so-called *"spaghetti code"*, so it could be a good habit to avoid them when possible. In the function code above a simple `Exit Function` would suffice :-) - It's accepted practice, however to use them handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness I added the code and checked if the sheet to be kept exists so in case it doesn't, there isn't an error raised.

Read the code's comments.

```
Public Sub DeleteSheetsExceptInFiles()

    Dim targetFile As String
    Dim targetDirectory As String
    Dim keepSheetName As String
    
    Dim str As String
    
    ' Basic error handling
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    ' Define directory, file and sheet name
    targetDirectory = "C:\Temp\"
    targetFile = Dir(targetDirectory & "*.xlsx")
    keepSheetName = "name of sheet to keep"
    
    ' Speed up process
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ' Loop through files
    Do While targetFile <> ""
        Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetDirectory & targetFile)
        
        
        ' Check if sheet to keep exists
        Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
        Dim keepSheetExists As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
            keepSheetExists = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(keepSheetName)
        On Error GoTo CleanFail
        
        ' Proceed if sheet exists
        If keepSheetExists = True Then
            For Each targetSheet In targetWorkbook.Worksheets
                
                ' Delete all sheets except the one to keep
                If targetSheet.Name <> keepSheetName Then
                    targetSheet.Delete
                End If
            
            Next targetSheet
        End If
        
        targetWorkbook.Close True

        targetFile = Dir()
        
    Loop
    

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
 
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "Something went wrong: " & Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```